# Pandas - pd.crosstab gives me incorrect classification

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, crosstab

I built a classifier and wanted to try out `pd.crosstab`. However, it seems to give me incorrect numbers of total elements which is confusing and I can't figure out why.

Actual code:

```
df_confusion = pd.crosstab(pd.Series(y_pred), pd.Series(y_test), 
                           rownames=['Predicted'], colnames= ['Actual'],
                           margins=True)
```

Typing in jupyter notebook: `df_confusion` yields

```
**Actual**   0.0      1.0   **All**

**Predicted**   

**0.0**    6529     1951        8480

**1.0**     718     208         926

**All**     7247    2159        9406**
```

whereas the total number of elements of each category 0 and 1 in *y_pred* and *y_test* are as follows:

```
sum(y_pred==0) equals 34264
sum(y_pred==1) equals 3514

sum(y_test==1) equals 34259
sum(y_test==0) equals 3519
```

**However importing confusion_matrix yields expected answers**

```
from sklearn.metrics  import confusion_matrix

confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)
array([[34259,     0],
       [    5,  3514]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Make sure you run your code directly in succession and check the results again.

Comment: What does `pd.isnull(y_pred).any()` and `pd.isnull(y_test).any()` return?

Comment: `pd.crosstab` is reporting the (non-NaN?) values as `0.0` and `1.0`. If `y_pred` and `y_test` contained only integer values, then these values would have remained integers. That the values are reported by `pd.crosstab` as floats suggests that `pd.Series` promoted the values to floats because of the presence of some non-integer value such as `np.nan`.

Comment: Thanks ! The answer to **pd.isnull(y_pred).any()** is False and it is the same for y_test

Comment: @unutbu pd.unique(y_pred) yields array([0, 1], dtype=int64) , same answer for y_test

Comment: @PriS: I can't think of a reason why this is happening. We might have to see a runnable example which reproduces the problem to make progress.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the total number of elements in the confusion matrix didn't match the number of elements in the series.
It was caused by wrong indices. One of my series was created by dropping rows from a dataframe, while the other was created in a loop. So the indices in the 2 series didn't match. I had to apply `reset_index(drop=True)` on the first series.